# Is there a way to require mandatory whitespace using Pest?

Tags: rust, language-design, peg, pest

I'm making an esolang based on a conlang, which rather inevitably involves whitespace-separated words. Contrary to a regular programming language using symbols, this means that I end up needing mandatory whitespace between nearly every single token.
This makes the grammar much harder to read, write, evolve and maintain; is there a smart way of making whitespace mandatory?
Like some overload of the ~ operator?

TL;DR
I'd like a concise way of expressing something like this:

```
WHITESPACE = ...
a = { "a" }
b = { "b" }
rule = [modifier]{ a ~ b }
```

That would match `a b` and `a        b` but not `ab`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pest's [atomic rule](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#atomic) to prevent implicit whitespace and handle it manually:

```
rule = @{ a ~ WHITESPACE+ ~ b }
a = { "a" }
b = { "b" }
WHITESPACE = _{ " " | "\t" }
```

Comment: This is more or less what I've done for my grammar, but it's extremely heavy just for mandatory whitespace... Looked around more and what I want definitely isn't part of Pest yet, so I will leave this question as unanswered for now.

Comment: @Brynhildr I can suggest to also open a "feature" issue in Pest's tracker: https://github.com/pest-parser/pest/issues